# xargs "too long argument list"

Tags: bash, xargs

I want to do something like this:

```
cat 5.txt | xargs -0 openssl prime
```

but xargs is saying that argument list is too long

---

Edit:

```
cat 3.txt | xargs -n 1 openssl prime | wc -l
```

works, thanks

Comment: hard to believe xargs would say "argument list too long" since you only give it three arguments.  what makes you think xargs says this?

Comment: what is the format of 5.txt?

Comment: for "cat 5.txt | xargs openssl prime" works but only for 725 lines ,"file 5.txt
5.txt: ASCII text
"

Comment: can you give us more information, like the actual errors you get?

Comment: how many nulls exist in 5.txt?

Comment: "how many nulls exist in 5.txt" how to check this?

Comment: I doubt there're any zeros inside, actually. Try not using `-0` and use `-n …` instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using `xargs`'s `-n`:

> Use at most max-args arguments per command line.

Also worth noting `xargs` can be made to

> Print the command line on the standard error output before executing it.

with `-t`, which is rather useful for debuging.

Comment: @asfsafsfsaf, don't use `-0`, man

Comment: @asfsafsfsaf, so what? 2946 * 4 = 11784, though I still don't see what that all `wc -l` exercise is about

Comment: @asfsafsfsaf, according to your previous data which you have deleted already (reasons unknown), `xargs -n4` [worked as well](http://serverfault.com/questions/496720/xargs-too-long-argument-list/496723?noredirect=1#comment555709_496723), you just couldn't get it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem sounds like you should not be using -0, -0 is for when you have your arguments in the file separated by null characters instead of $IFS which is usually whitespace.  If the file is formatted with one argument per line or with arguments separated by whitespace, omit the -0.

I'm also guessing that you don't intend it to run `openssl prime arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4...." but instead run`openssl prime arg1`then run`openssl prime arg2`, then`openssl prime arg3`, etc, in which case, add the -1 switch as well, which is shorthand for`-n 1`, if you really want to run one invocation of openssl per line of the file, you want:

```
xargs -1 openssl prime < 5.txt
```

or with the uuoc (useless use of cat)

```
cat 5.txt | xargs -1 openssl prime
```

on a non-gnu xargs which doesn't know the -1 option this would be:

```
xargs -n1 openssl prime < 5.txt
```

Comment: more like : openssl prime first line; openssl prime second line ...

Comment: xargs -1 openssl prime < 5.txt
xargs: wrong option -- '1'